# C Third party library cannot load the configuration(.ini) file from JAVA (using SWIG/JNA to connect)

Tags: java, c, dll, swig, jna

test.cxx file

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "test.h"

 int __declspec(dllexport) openFile() {
 FILE * fp;

 fp = fopen ("file.txt", "r");

 if(fp == NULL) 
   return 0;

 fclose(fp);

return 1;
}
```

test.h file:

```
 #ifndef __TEST_H__
 #define __TEST_H__
 #ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
 #endif
 int __declspec(dllexport) openFile();

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }
 #endif // __cplusplus
 #endif
```

Now if I create a dll(test.dll), using the following command

1. g++ -c test.cxx
2. g++ -shared test.o -o test.dll

Now I will access the dll from Java. So I am using SWIG to create a wrapper dll and acess the dll function.

My SWIG interface file (example.i)

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "windows.i"
%include "example.h"
%include "test.h"
```

example.cxx file:

```
  #include "example.h"
```

example.h file:

```
  #include "test.h"
```

Now I create the wrapper dll, using following command

1. swig -c++ -java example.i
2. g++ -c example.cxx  example_wrap.cxx
3. g++ -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o example.dll -L. test.dll

My Java class:

```
  public class main {
  static {
     System.loadLibrary("example");
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
       System.out.println(example.openFile());
  }
  }
```

When I run the Java code by following command

1. javac main.java
2. java main

Then jvm crash.. What can be the issue ? It seems like when C tries to open the file, JVM crash.

Comment: Just a wild guess. Could be that the library is looking in the location where the binary resides. If you wrap it with SWIG, the binary is the wrapper dll, which may reside elsewhere. Try to copy the ini file to the location of your wrapper dll

Comment: Thank you for the comment. All my dll's (including third party and wrapper dll and ini files) are in the same directory. I have tried the same with JNA (Java native access) and getting the same error. Do you think I am making some other mistake? Are there any way I can set to read from windows registry and copy the data in the registry? I will appreciate any response

Comment: Where is your "file.txt"? I suggest you to get the exe path in your dll, and put file.txt beside the exe file, and load it with absolute path.